# How to get comma-separated string values of XML elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can someone please help in the below requirement of fetching all the XML elements in a single comma separated string?

**XML**

```
<ClassNumbers>
  <class>
    10433
  </class>
  <class>
    11980
  </class>
  <class>
    13799
  </class>
  <class>
    17392
  </class>
  <class>
    11234
  </class>
</ClassNumbers>
```

Desired Output:

`10433,11980,13799,17392,11234`

Any suggestions in solving this with XPATH / XSLT are welcome.

Comment: @Marc : //class/text() gives all the elements but doesn't give them in a delimited format. I was more looking for delimited string with all the elements of the XML. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @kjhughes:  Thanks for editing the xml. I had difficulties using my chrome browser for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 option...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:if test="following::text()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Edit based on comments...

**XML Input**

```
<ListofCLassNbrs xmlns="getClassNumberData">
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>45</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>46</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>47</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
</ListofCLassNbrs>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <ClassNumberData>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ClassNumberData>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:if test="following::text()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<ClassNumberData>45,46,47</ClassNumberData>
```

If for some reason you need to specifically match `ClassNumber`, you can bind the namespace to a prefix...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:x="getClassNumberData"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  exclude-result-prefixes="x">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <ClassNumberData>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </ClassNumberData>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="x:ClassNumber">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:if test="following::text()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I tried your xslt but it failed with an error. Here is the actual XML

<ListofCLassNbrs xmlns="getClassNumberData">
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>45</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>46</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>47</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
</ListofCLassNbrs>

Could possibly try this with your xslt tool (if you have any)..

Comment: @KranthiBandaru - What is the error? What processor/tool are you using? It works fine for me with both Xalan and Saxon.

Comment: I used the following xslt

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="//ClassNumber">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:if test="following::text()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet> for the XMl I had in the earlier comment.

Comment: Here is the error 

TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-12-15 15:58:21,135] ERROR : Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='conf:/xslt/getClassNumbers.xslt'} against source XPath : s11:Body/child::*[position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[position()=1] reason : Unable to create an OMElement using XSLT result  {org.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator}
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unable to create an OMElement using XSLT result 
        at rg.apache.synapse.mediators.transform.XSLTMediator.performXSLT(XSLTMediator.java:302)

Comment: I even tried with the following XSLT

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="//ClassNumber/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:if test="following::text()">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>` 

even the above one fails with the same error

Comment: @KranthiBandaru - Did you try my XSLT example? The 2 examples you posted won't work with your actual XML. If you need to match `ClassNumber` specifically, I can update my answer. Your error seems to be that it's expecting XML as a result of the transform. I'm not sure if this is because the output method in your XSLT or something else. Try my example without changing anything and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: The actual XML i get from the webservice is below..

`<ListofCLassNbrs xmlns="getClassNumberData">
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>45</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>46</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
    <ClassNumberData>
        <ClassNumber>47</ClassNumber>
    </ClassNumberData>
</ListofCLassNbrs>`

Could you please modify your answer to fetch me the output like

`<ClassNumberData> 45,46,47 </ClassNumberData>`

Thanks
Kranthi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98027/discussion-between-kranthi-bandaru-and-daniel-haley).

Answer (score 3):

### XPath 2.0 Solution

```
string-join(//class/normalize-space(),',')
```

**Result**

```
10433,11980,13799,17392,11234
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/615d9281f110090eff532da8600ae395)</kbd>

Comment: I tried your solution but I get the following error.

SyntaxError: The string 'string-join(//class/normalize-space(),',')' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Then your XPath processor, unfortunately, is not understanding XPath 2.0, because this is a correct XPath 2.0 expression.

Comment: I use the following online website to test the XPATH.

Comment: http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

Not sure which xpath processor its using to display the results

Comment: That site only does XPath 1.0, not 2.0.    I've added a [live demo link](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/615d9281f110090eff532da8600ae395) that shows that the expression returns your desired result via XPath 2.0.

Comment: Here is my actual XML.. I tried using the website you mentioned for the below xml, but i get an error. Could you please help.
`<ListofCLassNbrs xmlns="getClassNumberData">
   <ClassNumberData>
      <ClassNumber>45</ClassNumber>
   </ClassNumberData>
   <ClassNumberData>
      <ClassNumber>46</ClassNumber>
   </ClassNumberData>
</ListofCLassNbrs>`

XPATH string : string-join(//ClassNumber/normalize-space(),',')

Comment: @KranthiBandaru - Your xml is in a default namespace. Since you're trying xpath 2.0, just use an asterisk for the prefix: `string-join(//*:ClassNumber/normalize-space(),',')`

Comment: Right, with a minor typo correction, @DanielHaley's XPath will succesfully ignore the default namespace: `string-join(//*:ClassNumberData/normalize-space(),',')`.   Alternatively (albeit less expeditiously), you can define namespace prefixes and use them in the XPath.

Comment: @kjhughes : Thanks for the update. The XPATH string works in the XPATH 2.0 processor, but do you have a solution for XPATH 1.0 . It looks like the ESB i'm using utilizes the XPATH 1.0

Thanks
Kranthi

Comment: XPath 1.0 alone isn't up to the task.   If you can't use an XPath 2.0 library, you'll need to augment processing outside of XPath such as via XSLT as @DanielHaley [shows for XSLT 1.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34296294/290085)  or Martin Honnen [shows for XSLT 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34296275/290085).

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 2.0 you can use `<xsl:value-of select="//class/normalize-space()" separator=","/>`. Make sure you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime