# Transform a comma separated string to several XML elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I need a command to do the reverse action of this: [How to get comma-separated string values of XML elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296223/how-to-get-comma-separated-string-values-of-xml-elements)

**Example**:

I have the following XML expression

```
<videos>
<video>
<keywords>tag1, tag2, tag3</keywords>
</video>
</videos>
```

And with the help of XPath I need to convert it in a way to get

```
<keywords>tag1</keywords>
<keywords>tag2</keywords>
<keywords>tag3</keywords>
```

as a result of

> XPath /videos/video/keywords

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**XPath is for selecting XML; XSLT is for transforming XML.**  This is really a task for XSLT rather than XPath because you're seeking to transform the XML into something new, not select XML that already exists.

If you'd be satisfied selecting comma-separated string values without wrapping them in `keywords` elements,

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
```

then you could use this XPath 2.0 expression:

```
tokenize(/videos/video/keywords, ',\s*')
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres is an ugly XPath 1.0 workaround in case of fixed list of tags - you can generate nodes by checking each value:

```
for $v in ("tag0", "tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "someOtherValue")
    let $csv := concat(", ", videos[1]/video[1]/keywords[1], ",")
    return if (contains($csv, concat(", ", $v, ","))) then <keywords>{$v}</keywords> else ()
```

The result is:

```
<keywords>tag1</keywords>
<keywords>tag2</keywords>
<keywords>tag3</keywords>
```